# Php возвращать ли Null вместо DateTime?

Tags: php

Есть некий класс "Task" который заполняется данными
 В метод setDate передается либо null либо временная строка,
 строка преобразуется в объект типа \DateTime()

Как сделать так что бы при получении даты через метод getDate()
 система не ломалась если свойство date содержит Null

Цель: сократить кол-во условий

Как решить проблему?

1. Заливать фейковую дату 0000-00-00 - но в php это как то странно работает проставляется месяц ноябрь по умолчанию
2. Перегрузить класс DateTime в DateTimeNull и возвращать null в метода - но это решение нарушает LSP и скорее всего в будущем вызовет массу проблем
3. Сделать адаптер над DateTime и возвращать 0000-00-00 дату, или null или еще что то еще что то на свое усмотрение
4. Не надо ничего делать, всегда проверять что метод getDate() содержит
5. Ваш вариант

---

```
class Task
{

    private $date;

    /**
     *
     * @param $dateTime null | \DateTime
     */
    function setDate($dateTime)
    {
        $this->date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D d M Y H:i:s +T', $dateTime);
    }

    /**
     * @param $dateTime
     * @return null|DateTime
     */
    function getDate($dateTime)
    {
        return $this->date;
    }


}

/* -------как сейчас ------- */
$tasks = new Tasks();
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    if (!$task->getDate()) {
        continue;
    }
    $task->getDate()->format('D');
}

/*  ------как надо-------- */
$tasks = new Tasks();
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    $task->getDate()->format('D');
}
```

Comment: `! $task->getDate() ?  $task->getDate('now')->format('D')  :  $task->getDate()->format('D') ;`